# Visualforce page rendered as pdf can be sent for Esign using Docusign

Tags: pdf, docusignapi, visualforce, docusignapextoolkit

Can we send Visualforce page rendered as pdf for Esignature using Docusign.

Cannot use template function provided by DocuSign as a number of components are dynamic which can't be done using Docusign template.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You want a VisualForce page turned into a PDF and then sent to DocuSign for signature?

The first part (turning a VisualForce page into a PDF) is the hard part. You need to accomplish that.

The usual technique is to have your application create a dynamic document on the fly, then send it to DocuSign. You can create PDFs dynamically using a software library.

But it is often easier to create an HTML document. If you send an HTML document to DocuSign, then it must use inline CSS styling (not an external style sheet) and must also include inline graphics via the [data: URL type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)